# Confusing arguments in functions

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm very new to Python and have frustrated so many times (guess that's common huh). Here I'm trying to have two user inputs (miles and gallons) and print out the result of (miles per gallons).

```
def final():
    def miles_per_gallons_calculation(miles, gallons,mpg):
        mpg=miles/gallons
        return str(mpg)+" miles per gallons"

    def user_input():
        miles = input("Miles?: ")
        gallons = input("Gallons?: ")
        float(miles)
        int(gallons)
        return miles
        return gallons
    user_input()
    miles_per_gallons_calculation()
final()
```

I get the error "input() takes no arguments (1 given)" but I gave no arguments! I've tried putting (and not putting in) arguments but I keep getting errors. Can you take a look and add in the arguments for the functions please?

UPDATE: Ok I changed the function names as suggested by you guys to avoid errors. But I'm still having trouble calling the function "miles_per_gallons_calculation" function. Since the 2nd function takes the output of the 1st function what argument do I put (or not put in) when calling the 2nd function up?
(the error I get is "miles_per_gallons_calculations takes 2 arguments (0 given)")

Comment: You have written *your own function named `input`*. This is shadowing the built-in. Use a different name.

Comment: ok will do. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you have called your inner function `input` as well. Your inner `input` function overwrites the built-in one, and since it doesn't take any arguments, you get this error. Just rename it to something else and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the input function so that is why you're getting the error. Change `def input():` to something like `def my_input():`. This will get rid of the name conflict you have in your code.